# NiFi ExecuteScript output is corrupted using zip4j

Tags: java, groovy, stream, apache-nifi, zip4j

```
@Grab('net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.2.8')
import net.lingala.zip4j.io.outputstream.ZipOutputStream;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.ZipParameters;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.enums.EncryptionMethod;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
    byte[] inputByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ZipOutputStream outputZipStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputByteStream, "password".toCharArray())

    //init the zip parameters
    ZipParameters zipParams = new ZipParameters()
    zipParams.setEncryptFiles(true)
    zipParams.setEncryptionMethod(EncryptionMethod.AES)
    zipParams.setFileNameInZip("records.csv")

    outputZipStream.putNextEntry(zipParams)
    outputZipStream.write(inputByteArray)
    outputZipStream.closeEntry()

    outputZipStream.close()
    outputByteStream.close()

    outputStream.write(outputByteStream.toByteArray())
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

I am zipping csv with a password using executescript written in groovy. The executescript processor is able to pass the flowfile to the next processor without a problem but that file is corrupted. The PutSFTP processor is complaining about the following error.[image]

The file is stored via SFTP nonetheless but I can't unzip it since its corrupted. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Does the user for that sftp processor have permission to make a filename change on the target system?

Comment: Yes it has. To note, transferring files via sftp without zipping works fine.

Comment: I don't t see in error message anything about corruption. Putsftp doesn't care about file content, even if you got zip corrupted. Please provide full stacktrace from log file to see the real error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyones reference, you need to close the inputStream manually after using to toByteArray: The following code should work:

```
@Grab('net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.2.8')
import net.lingala.zip4j.io.outputstream.ZipOutputStream;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.ZipParameters;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.enums.EncryptionMethod;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
    byte[] inputByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)
    inputStream.close() // this is what was missing in the original code

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ZipOutputStream outputZipStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputByteStream, "password".toCharArray())

    //init the zip parameters
    ZipParameters zipParams = new ZipParameters()
    zipParams.setEncryptFiles(true)
    zipParams.setEncryptionMethod(EncryptionMethod.AES)
    zipParams.setFileNameInZip("records.csv")

    outputZipStream.putNextEntry(zipParams)
    outputZipStream.write(inputByteArray)
    outputZipStream.closeEntry()

    outputZipStream.close()
    outputByteStream.close()

    outputStream.write(outputByteStream.toByteArray())
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 1):

While developing custom processor to unpack encrypted content, we have successfully used below code snippet to unzip password protected flowfiles using Lingala. Kindly please refer below code to replicate logic to ExecuteScript processor  -

```
import net.lingala.zip4j.io.inputstream.ZipInputStream;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.LocalFileHeader;

@Override
        public void unpack(final ProcessSession session, final FlowFile source, final List<FlowFile> unpacked) {
            final String fragmentId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            session.read(source, new InputStreamCallback() {
                @Override
                public void process(final InputStream in) throws IOException {
                    int fragmentCount = 0;

                    try (final ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in), UNPACK_PASSWORD.toCharArray())) {
                        LocalFileHeader zipEntry;
                        while ((zipEntry = zipIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                            if (zipEntry.isDirectory() || !fileMatchesWithEncryption(zipEntry)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            final File file = new File(zipEntry.getFileName());
                            final String parentDirectory = (file.getParent() == null) ? "/" : file.getParent();
                            final Path absPath = file.toPath().toAbsolutePath();
                            final String absPathString = absPath.getParent().toString() + "/";

                            FlowFile unpackedFile = session.create(source);
                            try {
                                final Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
                                attributes.put(CoreAttributes.FILENAME.key(), file.getName());
                                attributes.put(CoreAttributes.PATH.key(), parentDirectory);
                                attributes.put(CoreAttributes.ABSOLUTE_PATH.key(), absPathString);
                                attributes.put(CoreAttributes.MIME_TYPE.key(), OCTET_STREAM);

                                attributes.put(FRAGMENT_ID, fragmentId);
                                attributes.put(FRAGMENT_INDEX, String.valueOf(++fragmentCount));

                                unpackedFile = session.putAllAttributes(unpackedFile, attributes);
                                unpackedFile = session.write(unpackedFile, new OutputStreamCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void process(final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                                        StreamUtils.copy(zipIn, out);
                                    }
                                });
                            } finally {
                                unpacked.add(unpackedFile);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```